# Is it obligatory for us to go out somewhere today?

Tags: sentence-construction

I wonder if you could explain me it's possible to replace

> **Must we go out today?**

into

> **Is it obligatory for us to go out somewhere today?**

*Are both sentences idiomatic?*

Comment: The sentence with "obligatory" is grammatically correct, but *obligatory* is a rather formal ["two-dollar word"](http://nomistakes.org/two-dollar-words-make-look-like-ass/).  It's the kind of word you find in a legal document rather than everyday speech.

Comment: You could also say "Do we have to go out today?"

Answer (score 1):

The two sentences are not really the same and it's unlikely that a native speaker would ever use the second phrasing.

"Must we..." here does not necessarily indicate an obligation or following a rule. It is used more loosely to indicate dissatisfaction with some decision or plan.

-"I'm going to have another piece of cake."
-"Oh, must you? You've had eleven already!"

Comment: Agreed.  "Is it obligatory for us..." is more in line with "Is it required for us..." or "Do we need..." while "Must we..." is generally used as more of a complaint than a question.